# Batch script execution help

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, error

I've got an automated process that produces 100's of blend files for use in Unity. I need to change each of these files to fix some things. I've got other scripts that are ugly but get the job done, like renaming materials and object names and turn off auto smooth and double sided. Now I would like to generate a UV map and scale it to a real world size (I'm trying to use the [Magic-UV add-on](https://github.com/nutti/Magic-UV).) I've made this script:

```
import bpy

def ApplyWorldScaleUV():
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.layers = [True] * 20 # Show all layers

    for obj in scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            print(">>>> START >>>>     ApplyWorldScaleUV obj name: %s" %obj.name)       
            scene.objects.active = obj
            obj.select = True
                        
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66.0, island_margin=0.001, user_area_weight=0.0, stretch_to_bounds=False)

            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
            bpy.ops.uv.cube_project()
            bpy.ops.uv.muv_wsuv_measure()
            bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.uv.muv_wsuv_apply()
            
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            print(">>>> END >>>>     ") 
            
ApplyWorldScaleUV()
```

If I open a blender file, open this script in the text editor and run it, it works. But I've got 100's of files, so I want to automate it. When I try to run it from a command line (Windows 7 FYI) using:

```
blender.exe example.blend -P C:\temp\realWorldUV.py
```

I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\uv_magic_uv\muv_wsuv_ops.py", line 127, in execute
    orig_area = bpy.context.area.type
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

I'm quite confused by all the context issues, and I've been working on this for over a day.

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Comment: Try [https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Comment: I did this, but it's still the same error.  
`if __name__ == "__main__":
 ApplyWorldScaleUV()`

Comment: You might have to overwrite context when running from cmd. Check [https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context)

Comment: Can you try wrapping the `ApplyWorldScaleUV()` like this: `bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(ApplyWorldScaleUV)`.

Not sure, but this might be because the context is not right at the point of execution.

Comment: Tried wrapping it and it stops the error, but it also doesn't do it. It does't output my print messages either.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm just getting into scripting with blender